# MySQL load data infile with a field-prefix criterion

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I have a text file which has the following content (I have only shown the first few lines to illustrate that). They are in the form of key-value pair.

```
FIELD_A="Peter Kibbon",FIELD_B=31,FIELD_C="SCIENCE"
FIELD_A="James Gray",FIELD_B=28,FIELD_C="ARTS"
FIELD_A="Michelle Fernado",FIELD_B=25,FIELD_C="SCIENCE"
```

I want to import these data in a MySQL database using LOAD DATA FILE syntax to speed up the process. Is there any way that I can specify something like a field-prefix so that it can read the "value" part of each field.

I do not want to use MULTIPLE insert by parsing each line and each field, as this would slow down the process quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that all fields will be specified on each row and they are always in the same order, you can do something like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'your_file'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(@col1_variable, @col2_variable, @col3_variable)
SET column1 = REPLACE(@col1_variable, 'FIELD_A=', ''),
column2 = REPLACE(@col2_variable, 'FIELD_B=', ''),
column3 = REPLACE(@col3_variable, 'FIELD_C=', '');
```

You load the content of the file in variables first, then operate on those variables and assign the result to your columns.

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).